# Does the GIF 89a specification actually specify byte order?

Tags: image-processing, gif

In doing some research recently, I came across this [article](https://www.file-recovery.com/gif-signature-format.htm), which states:

> All multi-byte values in GIF structures are in little-endian order (low byte goes first).

However, in the [GIF89a specification](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt), I was unable to find any mention of byte ordering. Specific, in the section on Logical Screen Descriptor block discussion on Logical Screen Width, which I believe is the first section to utilize multi-byte numbers, no mention is made to the byte ordering of the numbers. This would lead me to believe that the byte ordering is the same as bit ordering within a byte (i.e. most significant byte first), but encoders seem to follow the opposite standard.

Is there mention of byte ordering in the specification, and if not, why is little endian used by encoders?

Comment: Page 2, section 4:  Multi-byte numeric fields are ordered Least Significant Byte first.

Comment: @Yves Daoust If you post as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: No need, you answered. (But you could say LSB first.)

Comment: Thank you again. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! I found it after all. For future readers, it is specified in the Glossary under "Byte Ordering".